# Elastic Search, java, grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, elasticsearch

I have implemented elastic search in our grails project.
In elastic search how do you write a DSL query to search details within an inner class?
For example if I have classes as follows:

```
class A {
 hasMany [b: B]
}

class B {
 hasMany [c: C]
}

class C {
 hasMany [d: D]
}

class D {
 String name
}
```

And I need to implement search for class A based on the property 'name' of class D.
I have implemented searchable in all the classes and also specified the inner classes as components.

While writing the query I tried to access it as b.c.d.name

Answer (score 0):

I've only just started working with elasticsearch, but I've add a little success with the following format:

```
must{
    term("a.b.c.name" : "${params.name}")
}
```